# Multiple infinite loop functions not working together RPI

Tags: python, function, raspberry-pi, infinite-loop

So I have 2 functions in my code, one which calculates the distance on a ultrasonic sensor and the other one uses a ps4 controller to control 2 motors. When I call the two of them together it only the top one works so for example:

controller()
sensor()

only the controller works and vise versa only the sensor works

I tried changing the code up a little and maybe change how the functions work and the order of the functions but nothing works, I expected the motors to work with the controller while also having the ultrasonic sensor work too.

Comment: Try to use separate threads.

Comment: @MichaelButscher do I have to import some module and how should I go about using threads? Thank you so much for the help really appreciate it :)

Comment: It is the `threading` module. There are some tutorials about it on the net.

Comment: You might also look at `concurrent.futures`.

Comment: Does it use any modules or how would it be imported and how would it work with my main code? Thank you :)